# How to detect if a photo is uploaded after taking the photo or chosen from library from iphone with php?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, safari

I am trying to detect the source of the photo which is uploaded by a user to my website with iPhone.. I want to see if it is uploaded after real time photo shooting or chosen from the photos in library. I want to detect this with php.. Is this possible?

Comment: At least from how I understand your question: No, I believe that it is not possible, while I don't have a Iphone I belive that the Iphone stores the image in the photo library right away so finding out whether it's "Fresh" or older from the picture library, at least from how you describe it, is highly unlikely. HOWEVER you could do some other checking by matching the current time against the photo's time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
             usingDelegate: (id ) delegate {

  if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
               UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
          || (delegate == nil)
          || (controller == nil))
      return NO;

  UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

  // Displays saved pictures and movies, if both are available, from the
  // Camera Roll album.
  mediaUI.mediaTypes =
      [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];

  // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
  // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
  mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;

  mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

  [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
  return YES;
  }
- (IBAction) showSavedMediaBrowser {
  [self startMediaBrowserFromViewController: self
                                  usingDelegate: self];
  }
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
          didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

  NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
  UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToUse;

  // Handle a still image picked from a photo album
  if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
          == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

  ```
  editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
              UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
              UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  if (editedImage) {
      imageToUse = editedImage;
  } else {
      imageToUse = originalImage;
  }
  // Do something with imageToUse
  ```

  }

  // Handle a movied picked from a photo album
  if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
          == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

  ```
  NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
              UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

  // Do something with the picked movie available at moviePath
  ```

  }

  [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
  [picker release];
  }